# Is it possible with sencha touch native app to still run in the background?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha touch and I am trying to create a native app using phonegap in iOS and Android.

We need to get data from a device to the phone through bluetooth, and have it still receive data even if the app is closed.

Is this possible with sencha touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default this is not possible with Phonegap/Cordova, when you suspend an app JavaScript execution stops too. There are however plugins that accomplish this. A simple google search gives results like

https://github.com/jocull/phonegap-backgroundjs

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much Rob, i`ll try the link that you gave soon..if this really could be done, now i`m a bit worried if it will be rejected by apple. Do you have any idea if this would be accepted or rejected??thanks

Comment: Adding background services is not a reason for rejection with Apple. The native side of the plugin is using features that a native app could use too. Of course you have to thoroughly test you app so that you don't drain your user's batteries.